# Exceeding a possessive adjective before subject pronouns

Tags: grammar, adjectives, pronouns

Is there any possibility for exceeding a possessive adjective before subject pronouns?
For example: can we use a structure as

> Historically, in his seminal article, Markus introduced several important suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by *exceeding*: I think you have the wrong word, but I don't know what you intended.

But yes, your sentence is a perfectly grammatical and idiomatic use of [cataphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphora).

Comment: Thank you so much. I mean the sentence "Historically,  Markus introduced in his seminal article" in lieu of that written above.

Answer (score 0):

No. Markus does not introduce anything historically. He just introduces it.

Adverbs modify verbs. There, *historically* modifies *introduced*. That doesn't make sense.

What are you trying to say? That he made history by making the suggestions? That he made historical references? That he was famous for making them? That history tells us that he introduced them, but the historic record is wrong?

And I don't understand *exceeding*, either.

More, information, please!

Comment: Adverbs also modify whole clauses. I see no problem with _Historically_ as a clausal adverb.